# Python Regex: replace multiple possibilities of substring

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, str-replace

I want to remove the indicator like `Fig 1.` in string `caption`, where `caption` may be:

```
# each line is one instance of caption
"Figure 1: Path of Reading Materials from the Web to a Student."
"FIGURE 1 - Travel CP-net"
"Figure 1 Interpretation as abduction, the big picture."
"Fig. 1. The feature vector components"
"Fig 1: IMAGACT Log-in Page"
"FIG 1 ; The effect of descriptive and interpretive information, and Inclination o f Fit"
...
```

I've tried `caption = re.sub(r'figure 1: |fig. 1 |figure 1 -', '', caption, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`, but it looks messy: do I really need to list all the possibilities manually? Is there any element re code to match 'em all?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You may shorten the pattern to `r'\bfig(?:\.|ure)?\s+1(?:\s*[-:])?'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use an optional part to match `ure` and use an optional character class to match the `:`, `.`, `;` or `-`

If you want to match other digits than 1, use `\d+`

```
\bfig\.?(?:ure)? 1[^\S\r\n]*[:.;–-]?
```

- `\bfig` Match fig preceded by a word boundary
- `\.?` Match an optional dot
- `(?:ure)?` Optionally match `ure`
- `1` Match a space and `1`
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Match 0+ occurrences of a whitespace char except newlines
- `[:.;–-]?` Optionally match any of the listed in the character class

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aNm3Z7/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jAEBOs)

Example code to also match the whitespace after the character class:

```
caption = re.sub(r'\bfig\.?(?:ure)? 1[^\S\r\n]*[:.;–-]?[^\S\r\n]', '', caption, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thx! but an interesting example:
```
caption = "FIGURE 1 - Travel CP-net"
re.sub(r'\bfig\.?(?:ure)? 1[^\S\r\n]*[:.;-]?[^\S\r\n]', '', caption, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# "Travel CP-net"

caption = "FIGURE 1 – The system diagram"
re.sub(r'\bfig\.?(?:ure)? 1[^\S\r\n]*[:.;-]?[^\S\r\n]', '', caption, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
# "– The system diagram"
```
why is that?